# how can i read from the middle of a really big file(1127k). assembly

Tags: file, assembly, x86-16

i want to read from the middle of the file(1127k) but i cant because i can mov to cx just 65200
because it is word

this is the code:

```
mov ah, 3Dh             
mov al, 0               
mov dx,offset FileName
int 21h
mov [Handle], ax

mov ah, 42h  
mov al, 00
mov bx, [Handle]
mov cx, 0
mov dx, 65200
int 21h                
jc      @@Err
```

i thought that i can use edx but i dont know how i do that int 21h will use edx and not dx

tnx for the helpers :)

Comment: Refer to [the documentation](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/441-dos_fn_42h__set_file_pointer.html).  The offset is in CX:DX, so just put the high bits into CX.

Comment: yes but yet i cant go to the middle i can go just (65200*2)

Comment: ask for the length of the file, then divide by 2?

Comment: AFAIK, the `int 21h` interface is entirely 16-bit.  Everything will use only the 16-bit registers (ax, bx, ...) never the 32-bit or 64-bit registers (eax, rax, etc).

Comment: @Gad I don't think you have understood correctly.  For example, if you want to move to byte 1'000'000 you'd set CX to 15 and DX to 16'960 because 1'000'000 = 15·65536 + 16'960.

Comment: oh thank you very much!!!